# Ember.js 2. Using nested templates is more RAM consuming?

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm wondering if using **nested templates** it's very **RAM consuming**...

Something like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.route('login');
  this.route('authors', {path: 'authors'}, function() {
    this.route('author', {path: ':author_id'}, function() {
      this.route('book', {path: ':book_id'}, function() {
        this.route('cart', {path: 'cart'});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

is **more RAM heavy** than this?

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.route('login');
  this.route('authors', {path: '/authors'});
  this.route('author', {path: '/author/:author_id'});
  this.route('book', {path: '/book/:book_id'});
  this.route('cart', {path: '/cart/:cart_id'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both routing maps will consume roughly the same amount of memory. There are likely a lot of other things in your apps that are consuming quite a bit more memory than the routing layer. You should generally not decide which routing layout to use based on potential memory consumption, but rather based on how your UI and URLs will look like.